# Word font substitution in templates

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I'm trying to build a Microsoft Word template for use by people who do not necessarily have some of the fonts that the template prefers.

In CSS one can define a "font-family", such as `font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;` or `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` (which isn't really the standard meaning for "font family", but never mind). But in Word, my understanding (from other Superuser questions) is that Word doesn't have a provision for font substitution in a document.

But is there a way to do the font substitution in a *template*, as opposed to a document?

My intended use is documents for print and PDF, not for web, so the CSS solution is not an option.

I have my ancient Word 2003 on my desktop, but I can use a more recent version if that will solve the problem.

Related question in case I have to use desktop publishing software instead of just Word: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/111434/font-substitution-in-scribus

Answer (score 1):

#### Word doesn't have a provision for font substitution in a document.

Actually it does.

> The easiest way to figure out what font substitution Word is doing in
>   a document is to follow these steps:
>
> 1. Display the Word Options dialog box. (In Word 2007 click the Office button and then click Word Options. In Word 2010 and Word 2013
>      display the File tab of the ribbon and then click Options.)
> 2. At the left side of the screen click Advanced.
> 3. Scroll down to the Show Document Content section. (See Figure 1.)
>
>    [image: Figure 1. The advanced options in the Word Options dialog box.]
> 4. Click the Font Substitution button.
>
> What happens at this point depends on whether there are substituted
>   fonts in your document. If there are no font substitutions within the
>   document, Word informs you and there is nothing more to do. If there
>   are font substitutions, Word displays the Font Substitution dialog
>   box. (See Figure 2.)
>
> [image: Figure 2. The Font Substitution dialog box.]
>
> The dialog box quickly shows you the missing fonts and what Word used
>   to substitute for each missing font. If you pick one of the missing
>   fonts, at the bottom of the dialog box you can specify a different
>   font to be substituted, if desired.
>
> Note, as well, the <kbd>Convert Permanently</kbd> button. This button
>   is equivalent to doing a Find and Replace to change all the missing
>   fonts to the specified replacement fonts. It obviously affects the
>   formatting within your document, and no more on-the-fly substitutions
>   will occur.
>
> If you are interested in knowing which fonts are similar to a given
>   font, then this online resource may be instructive:
>
> http://www.identifont.com/similar.html
>
> All you need to do is type in a font name and when you click the
>   <kbd>Go</kbd> button you'll see typefaces considered similar to the
>   one you questioned.

Source [Finding Word's Font Substitutes (Microsoft Word)](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T012657_Finding_Words_Font_Substitutes.html)